# How to add other language (like German) in Magento 2 stable version?

Tags: magento2, language, magento-2.0

I installed Magento 2 stable version. and run `static:deploy` command. When I change language in locale admin, no change language.

How to add language package? or any other solution?

Comment: Afaik there are no translation at this point for Magento 2. We need to wait a certain time untill they'll be available. In the other side, you can use the Magento inline translations.

Answer (score 3):

There are Magento 2 translation projects on crowdin: 
https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2

As of now the German language pack is 39% translated.

You can download the files from [there](https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2/de#).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was able to add a custom language pack in /app/i18n/test/de_de/de_DE.csv - but how do I integrate the different files I downloaded from crowdin? I expected something like /app/i18n/test/de_de/Customer/i18n/de_DE.csv, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Anna. Thank you for the reference to crowdin. Once we download the language folder from crowdin, how we can add it to Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

There's a german language pack on github: https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE

Comment: We use this on our Dev envs and its working perfectly fine. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use inline translation as was already suggested in comments. You can enable it in Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.

The other option is to create your own language pack. It is easy and very well described here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html. Do not run i18n:pack command in step #3, but copy file from step #1 to the directory you create in step #4.

You can share your language pack on GitHub and publish on Packagist, so other people will be able to use your language pack and participate in translation.